How to compile LLVM libfuzzer after modifying its code?
I've made some changes to LLVM libfuzzer source code (under compiler-rt/lib/fuzzer). Now I hope to recompile the libfuzzer so I can use the modified one.
Recompile the whole LLVM works while it takes time. Is there any way to only compile libfuzzer? Thank you.
